# Formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

Tags: custom-object, formula, process-builder

In short, the following formula is giving me this error:

> formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

```
[[Developing_Contractors__c].Contractor_Account_Contact__c.FirstName
 & ' ' & 
[Developing_Contractors__c].Contractor_Account_Contact__c.LastName
 & ' - ' & 
IF([Developing_Contractors__c].Principle_Owner__c = true, "Principle or Owner", null)
 & ' / ' & 
IF([Developing_Contractors__c].Sales_Associate__c = true, "Sales Associate", null)
 & ' / ' & 
IF([Developing_Contractors__c].Installation_Technician__c = true, "Installation Tech", null)
 & ' / ' & 
IF([Developing_Contractors__c].Service_Technician__c = true, "Service Tech", null)
 & ' / ' & 
IF([Developing_Contractors__c].Other_Support_Staff__c = true, "Other Staff", null)
 & BR()
 & BR()
```

Additional details:
I have a custom object (Developing_Contractors__c) that has a master-detail relationship to Accounts and a lookup field to the Account's Contacts. There are 5 checkboxes labled with appropriate employee titles. There is also a long text field and a checkbox called Add_Attendee__c.

I am creating a process in process builder that when the Add Attendee check box is checked will take the contact's first and last name and their title and add it to the long text area followed by two line breaks.

The output should look something like:

Joe Contractor - Principle or Owner / Installation Tech

I am doing this because I want to make sure that when the user adds contacts to the list they are definitely related to the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra opening square bracket in your first line:

```
[[Developing_Contractors__c]...
```